# Updating _id field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, crud, insert-update

I want to update my _id field in one of the document ( shown below ).

```
{
_id : ObjectId("586d9d5d23352af1a4aa05f7"),
name: "Soham",
age : 99,
city : "XYZ"
}
```

So I ran the below steps:

```
var doc = db.names.find({name:"Soham"});
doc._id = 111 ; -- 111 is not present in that collection for any document
db.names.remove({_id:ObjectId("586d9d5d23352af1a4aa05f7")});
db.names.insert(doc);
```

The first 3 lines haven't threw any error, but the moment I ran the insert command, it threw error. Can anyone please let me know what's going wrong.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: You should read the documentation first. The `_id` field is the **primary key** SQL equivalent in MongoDB an it's format is [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/). It has a well defined structure. So, you **cannot** set an arbitrary value as id for a document. Second, you should **never** do that. What's your purpose?

Comment: @guzgarcia `_id` in MongoDB is not necessarily an `ObjectId`, it can be anything you want, including a complex object.

Comment: @Soham: Please include the error thrown

Comment: Use `findOne` instead of `find` to return the document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is throwing an error, because you **can't update the _id field**.

In order to set a new id, first you find the document (using findOne, since you search just for 1 document), than need to create a new document with new id and insert it, than we can safe delete the old:

```
var doc = db.names.find_one({name:"Soham"});
doc._id = 111 ; 
db.names.insert(doc);
db.names.remove({_id:ObjectId("586d9d5d23352af1a4aa05f7")});
```

Comment: Thank u so much, yes it worked. I was doing the same thing, but instead of findOne I was using just find. Anyway, findOne worked. Thanks again.

Comment: It seems find or findOne is not the issue, we have to first insert and then remove not the other way round.

Comment: No, not an issue, but: find will return a cursor, which will evaluate into a list. findOne will return just 1 document.